# Fixed point of the mean of all operators is fixed point for each operator

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**Problem:** Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$.

Let $g \cdot v$ denotes the usual left multiplication of the matrix $g$ with the vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $T = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{r}g_i }{|G|}$. $T $ is also a linear operator.
Prove that $T(v)=v$ implies $g_i \cdot v = v$ for all $i$.

Please give some hint. I am unable to make a progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since $T(v)=v$, it suffices to show that $g_i\cdot T(v)=T(v)$.